# Anchors not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having a problem with anchors. It jumps to the middle of the page- no smooth scroll or nothing what so ever. I read something that when your `<div>` is not long enough it will not scroll so I tried to make it higher, but still nothing.

HTML

```
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <title></title>



    <!--Stylesheets-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/design.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="styles/fonts.css">        
    <!--[if IE]<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/msiefonts.css"><![endif]-->

    <!--Scripts Here-->
    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/scrollable.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/responsive_nav.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
<div id="wrap">    

            <div class="top-container-box"> 

                     <div class="logo">
                        <img src="pictures/logo.png" alt="logo" />
                     </div>
             </div>

         <div class="container">   

                   <div id="scroller-anchor"></div>  
                        <div id="menu">
                        <div class="nav_logo"></div>
                        <nav>
                          <ul class="nav">
                                <li><a href="#">&#x2630;</a></li>
                                <li><a href="index.php?site=home">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="index.php?site=about">About Me</a></li>
                                <li><a href="index.php?site=works">Works</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#contact" rel="" class="anchorLink">Contact</a></li>
                          </ul>
                        </nav>  
                        </div>

        <div id="break-point"></div>   

            <div class="lower-container-box">
                    <section class="textbox">
                            <p class="first-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint o       ccaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                    </section>           

                    <section class="textbox2">
                            <p class="second-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint o       ccaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                    </section> 

                    <section class="textbox3">
                            <p class="third-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint o       ccaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                    </section>


                    <section class="textbox4">
                        <a name="contact" id="contact"></a>
                                <div id="contact_form">

                                        <form name="form1" id="ff" method="post" action="insert.php"> 
                                            <label>
                                                <span>Name*:</span>
                                            <input type="text" placeholder="Please enter your name" name="name" id="name">
                                            </label>

                                            <label>
                                            <span>City*:</span>    
                                            <input type="text" placeholder="Please enter your city" name="city" id="city" required>
                                            </label>

                                            <label>
                                            <span>Phone:</span>
                                            <input type="tel" placeholder="Please enter your phone" name="phone" id="phone">
                                            </label>

                                            <label>
                                            <span>Email*:</span>
                                            <input type="email" placeholder="youremail@gmail.com" name="email" id="email" required>
                                            </label>

                                            <input class="sendButton" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Send">
                                            <!--?php include 'insert.php' ?>-->
                                       </form>
                               </div>
                    </section> 

            <div>

        </div>



    </div>        
          <div id="footer">
          <div id="footer-container">
          <p id="footer-text">Copyright &#169; [] [2014] All Rights Reserved!</p>           
                          <ul>
                                <li><a href="index.php?site=home">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="index.php?site=about">About Me</a></li>
                                <li><a href="index.php?site=works">Works</a></li>
                                <li><a href="index.php?site=contact">Contact</a></li>
                          </ul>
         </div>              
        </div>  
</div>



<!--<script src="scripts/sticky.js"></script>-->

</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click", 'a[href^="#"]', function () {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
        }, 500);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Is the click event actually called or are you applying the click before the elements are rendered?

Comment: I haven't called it. I have the script in external file and right before </body> tag. EDIT: lied, it is in the top, after jquery.

Comment: I removed the double ID and now it is going to the contact form, but there is still no smooth-scroll. Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at the [scrollTo plugin](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/)

Comment: Removing the dupe id and it runs fine: http://jsfiddle.net/6hZ8u/ And I missed the comment, than you need to wrap the code in ready... And `$(this).attr("href")` would be easier to read than `$.attr()`

Comment: @epascarello I did it. and then it jumps to the location. I wrapped the function inside $(function() {} and then it doesn't even jump to the anchor anymore. What am I missing here? Thanks.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6hZ8u/ works fine, not sure what your issue is. Are you cached with older code? Any errors in console. If you add log lines in the click, do you see it?

Comment: @epascarello I cleared the cache. and added console.log () under the click function and it doesn't log anything. I'm so dumb right now. How do I log it again?

Comment: Is the menu loaded dynamically?

Comment: No. Just HTML. Forget the .php link, I will change these to the anchors once I get it to work.

Comment: Update the question with the full html that you have now.

Comment: Well your code is still missing the document ready if that is what is in your JS file still. Change `$('a').click(function () {` to `$(document).on("click", 'a[href^="#"]', function () {`

Comment: @user2983295 in the full HTML you provided, where is included the script you mentioned in the next code block?

Comment: @matewka and the javascript we are talking about is scrollable.js

Comment: @epascarello Hey. So do you have any idea what might be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two elements with the same `id` attribute. It's forbidden and causes your problem. Remove the `id` from the anchor in `<li>` and everything will be fine.

```
<li><a href="#contact" rel="" class="anchorLink">Contact</a></li>
```

Here's the link to working example: **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EwA27/)**

---

**EDIT**:

Of course, remember to wrap your jQuery with `$(document).ready` method, or its shortcut:

```
$(function() {
    $('a').click(function () {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
    }, 500);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Just wrote in my comment that I removed it and now it jumps to the right place, but there is still no smooth- scroll. Any suggestions?

Comment: @user2983295 There __is__ smooth scroll. Did you take a look at my jsFiddle example?

Comment: Did you wrap the script with any kind of `onload`? Take a look at my edit.

Comment: as soon as I add this $(document).ready it doesn't work at all anymore.

Comment: How can you tell it doesn't work __at all anymore__ since it never did?

Comment: well I meant somewhat worked before (it jumped to the location).

Comment: got it working: modified the script! Thanks for the help guys!